# Regex to avoid all words between {{ and }}

Tags: regex, spell-checking, spelling

I am using https://github.com/tbroadley/spellchecker-cli.

I have a JSON file that I'd like to run spellChecker on and it looks like this:

```
{
  "abc.editGroupsMaxLengthError": "Maximum {{charLen}} characters"
}
```

I would like to know how can all words between `{{` and `}}` be ignored by the spellchecker.

I tried with

```
[A-Za-z]+}}
```

as documented here https://github.com/tbroadley/spellchecker-cli#ignore-regexes to ignore regex.

but it doesn't seem to use `}}` or `{{` for some reason.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: In regular expressions braces have a special meaning. To denote literal ones, you need to escape them with a backslash.

Comment: This seems to ignore incorrect spellings with just alphabets outside of {{}} as well @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: That sounds like the text is pretokenized first. What input does the regex engine "see"/get?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you elaborate on  What input does the regex engine "see"/get, please?

Comment: Most probably, you will get help [here](https://github.com/tbroadley/spellchecker-cli/issues/79) some day. After the tool is enchanced, see [this](https://github.com/tbroadley/spellchecker-cli/issues/42#issuecomment-433032852): "*Dictionaries are intended to ignore single words, not longer blocks of text.*"

Comment: Or, try [this approach](https://github.com/tbroadley/spellchecker-cli/issues/42#issuecomment-637150577) with comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `{{...}}` substrings with `<!-- spellchecker-disable -->` / `<!-- spellchecker-enable -->` tags, see [this Github issue](https://github.com/tbroadley/spellchecker-cli/issues/42#issuecomment-637150577).

So, make sure your JSON looks like

```
{
  "abc.editGroupsMaxLengthError": "Maximum <!-- spellchecker-disable -->{{charLen}}<!-- spellchecker-enable --> characters"
}
```

And the result will be

```
C:\Users\admin\Documents\1>spellchecker spellchecker -f spellchecker_test.json
Spellchecking 1 file...

spellchecker_test.json: no issues found
```

To wrap the `{{...}}` strings in a certain file in Windows you could use PowerShell, e.g., for a `spellchecker_test.json` file:

```
powershell -Command "& {(Get-Content spellchecker_test.json -Raw) -replace '(?s){{.*?}}','<!-- spellchecker-disable -->$&<!-- spellchecker-enable -->' | Set-Content spellchecker_test.json}"
```

In *nix, Perl is preferable:

```sh
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\{\{.*?}}/<!-- spellchecker-disable -->$&<!-- spellchecker-enable -->/s' spellchecker_test.json
```

Comment: The values in JSON files are used to replace text on the web app, cannot add <!-- -->

Comment: @SKhurana then you are stuck and will have to wait till the Github issue #79 will be resolved.